# ColdFusion 9: Strip HTML tags out of specific parts of a string

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I've been cracking my head over this for quite some time.

I currently build a custom BB-Code function as part of a project at work. But I don't get it to work at one point: a [code] block.
Using **ColdFusion regex**, I want to replace the **<** and **>** characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, but only on HTML betweeen the [code] blocks.
So, how can I restrict a regex expression to the part of the string which is between the [code] blocks.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: -1: Lack of research.  There are already way too many questions asking "how do i use regex to parse xml?", and even more numerous answers all saying: use a XML parser, regex won't cut it!

Comment: @bdares I know about those parsers, but I'm not allowed to use them. I'm limited to ColdFusion.

Comment: Okay, I'll concede that this is possible if you assume that there are no nested `<code>` tags.  Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the ColdFusion regex syntax so I can't supply a working example.

Comment: Invalid markup like nested [code] blocks and similar stuff will be stripped out, so no worries about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in ColdFusion you'll have to iterate over the string, searching for occurrences of "[code]". When you find such an occurrence, read in the string until you hit "[/code]". Take that string and do a replaceList to replace the characters. Use the removeChars and insert functions to replace the old string with the new. One problem with using regular expressions in this context is that the CF function REReplace can't replace a pattern with another pattern, only with a string.

Comment: You're welcome! Would you mind accepting my answer? By the way, HTMLEditFormat() would also work in place of replaceList().

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot that. XP

Answer (score 1):

For those who stumble upon this question and could use an answer as well, I'll provide an example for parsing HTML in [code] blocks. Looks somewhat messy though:

```
<cfset contents = form.yourString />

<cfset substring1= "[code]" />
<cfset occurrences1 = ( Len(contents) - Len(Replace(contents,substring1,"","ALL"))) / Len(substring1) />
<cfset substring2= "[/code]" />
<cfset occurrences2 = ( Len(contents) - Len(Replace(contents,substring2,"","ALL"))) / Len(substring2) />

<cfif occurrences1 EQ occurrences2 AND occurrences1 GT 0 AND occurrences2 GT 0>
  <cfset loopinstance = occurrences1 />
<cfelse>
  <cfif occurrences1 LT occurrences2>
      <cfset loopinstance = occurrences1 />
  <cfelse>
      <cfset loopinstance = occurrences2 />
  </cfif>
</cfif>

<cfloop index="code_loop" from="1" to="#loopinstance#">
  <cfscript>
      // prepare variables //
      code_string = contents; 
      startpos = FindNoCase("[code]", code_string); 
      startpos = Evaluate(startpos + 6); // adjust the correct position of string in question 
      endpos   = FindNoCase("[/code]", code_string); 
      code_string = Mid(code_string, startpos, Evaluate(endpos - startpos)); // extract the string between code brackets 
      //** Replace-Codes are extensible depending on the used programming languages **//
      code_string = ReplaceNoCase(code_string, "<","&lt;", "ALL"); 
      code_string = ReplaceNoCase(code_string, ">","&gt;", "ALL"); 
      //** process conversion of [code] block **//
      startpos = FindNoCase("[code]", contents); // reevaluating the start and end positions for main string 
      startpos = Evaluate(startpos + 6); // adjust the correct position of form string 
      endpos   = FindNoCase("[/code]", contents); 
      contents = RemoveChars(contents, startpos, Evaluate(endpos - startpos)); // remove the extracted string 
      contents = Insert(code_string, contents, Evaluate(startpos - 1)); // insert the processed code block to the original position 
      contents = ReplaceNoCase(contents, "[code]", "[coded]", "ONE"); // "flagging" the processed [code] block as finished by adding a "d" 
      contents = ReplaceNoCase(contents, "[/code]", "[/coded]", "ONE"); // "flagging" the processed [code] block as finished by adding a "d" 
  </cfscript>
</cfloop>

<!--- This is the regex to turn a written [code] block into an escaped HTML block --->
<cfscript>
  contents = REReplaceNoCase(contents, "\[coded\](.*?)\[/coded\]", "<div id =""code_test"">Escaped Code: <br />\1</div>", "ALL"); 
</cfscript>
```

I hope this will help some people who have a hard time following @David Faber's help.